# Storing specific shared variables in CPU

Tags: memory, gpu, theano

Is it possible in theano to selectively choose some shared variables in the CPU? I have a huge matrix in the output layer over entire vocabulary (~2M) that wouldn't fit in the GPU memory. I have experimented with reducing its size thro' sampling, but I want to see if I can use the entire matrix. One way I could do is to use `device=cpu,init_gpu_device=gpu` in theano flags. But, this seem to use GPU only on a need basis. I checked the tutorial and it doesn't seem to have more details.

I wonder if it is possible to specify one or few shared variables to be stored in cpu. One can do this when creating the shared variable I guess. Having some of the variables in GPU will be faster than having everything in CPU right? Or does theano somehow figure out which ones to implicitly keep/move automatically? Would appreciate some explanation.

Comment: When I add the `device=cpu,init_gpu_device=gpu` flags, it slows down my code by at least 4x, which I have tested now. And obviously, I will prefer to move the computation and most of the variables in GPU. Any suggestions?

Comment: The output layer is (probably) not stored in a shared variable so can you confirm you're talking about the shared variable storing your input data? Also, it is possible to choose to put some shared variables in GPU memory and some in host memory, but the speed impact can be quite significant; can you explain in more detail what types of data you're thinking of storing where? P.S. you can edit your question to add additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In newer Theano (I forgot Theano 0.8.2 or the dev version of Theano 0.9), there is a different interface. You can do theano.shared(data, target='cpu')

Continue to initialize the GPU as you did before.